# How do I get 2 lists with tag contents from the XML that include missing values?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have a XML file of a few thousand records, from which I want to extract:

- The city: tag 110 code c (for example Berlin)
- The library code: tag 110 code g (for example D-Bbbf)

I want would like to get a dataframe of all the cities next to the library code. **But if the library code (code="g") does not exist, then I would like NaN** or something else dat inditcates that there is no value. So for example

```
df = {'Cities': [Berlin, London], 'Codes': [D-Bbbf, NaN]}
```

This is a piece of the XML:

```html
<marc:record>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">39612</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="003">DE-633</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20161109000000.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="008">161109n|||||||a|||              a</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield tag="110" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">Bibliothek für Bildungsgeschichtliche Forschung</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">Berlin</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="g">D-Bbbf</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record><marc:record>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">30006648</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="003">DE-633</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20161109000000.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield tag="110" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">The National Archives</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">London</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
```

This is what I have tried:

```html
# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Data= {'Cities':[],
        'Code':[]}

# Read the XML file
with open('oefen.xml', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'html.parser')   
    
for record in soup.find_all(tag="110"):
    find = record.find_all('[code="g"]')

for code in record:
    if find is not None:
            City = record.select_one('[code="c"]') # select city
            Code = record.select_one('[code="g"]') # select code
            Data['Cities'].append(City.get_text(strip=True))
            Data['Code'].append(Code.get_text(strip=True))      
    else:
        print(NaN)
print(Data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it is not necessary to work with these list, its easier to use one list of dicts - While iterating your records check if element your looking for is available to append its text or `None`:

```
for record in soup.find_all('marc:record'):
    data.append({
        'City' : e.get_text(strip=True) if (e := record.select_one('[code="c"]')) else None, # select city
        'Code' : e.get_text(strip=True) if (e := record.select_one('[code="g"]')) else None  # select code
    })
```

#### Example

```
xml='''
<marc:record>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">39612</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="003">DE-633</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20161109000000.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="008">161109n|||||||a|||              a</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield tag="110" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">Bibliothek für Bildungsgeschichtliche Forschung</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">Berlin</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="g">D-Bbbf</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record><marc:record>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">30006648</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="003">DE-633</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20161109000000.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield tag="110" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">The National Archives</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">London</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
'''

# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'lxml')
for record in soup.find_all('marc:record'):
    data.append({
        'City' : e.get_text(strip=True) if (e := record.select_one('[code="c"]')) else None, # select city
        'Code' : e.get_text(strip=True) if (e := record.select_one('[code="g"]')) else None  # select code
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| City | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Berlin | D-Bbbf |
| London | None |

---

### EDIT

If you not using latest python version, this would be an alternativ to check with `walrus operator`:

```
...
data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'lxml')
for record in soup.find_all('marc:record'):
    try:
        city = record.select_one('[code="c"]').get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        city = None
    try:
        code = record.select_one('[code="g"]').get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        code = None
    data.append({
        'City' : city,
        'Code' : code
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message: `code`File "<ipython-input-6-05fcff83b9a7>", line 31
    'City' : e.get_text(strip=True) if (e := record.select_one('[code="c"]')) else None, # select city
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`code`

Comment: Is your `python` version up to date? Added an alternativ approache to EDIT section of my answer, that uses `try / except`.